# python read files from hard disk and return result depending on the pattern found

Tags: python, file, design-patterns

what i wanna do is this;
 - read files from hard drive and find a pattern like `the` see if the file contains this string if it does return true or return false. In the function call it should print out nicely saying `the found in file.txt etc.

this is what i have came up with so far

```
import os
path = '../'
folder = os.listdir(path);

y = {}
n = {}

def bla(pattern):
    for book in folder:
        if book[-3:] == 'txt':
            data = open(path+''+book).read()
            if pattern in sanitize(data):
                y[pattern] = book + " contains " + pattern
                return True
            else :
                n[pattern] = book + " does not contain " + pattern
                return False

if bla('jane'):
    print(y['jane']) 
    print(n['jane'])
```

desired output is this;

1.txt contains 'the'
2.txt does not contain 'the'
3.txt contains 'the'
4.txt does not contain 'the'

this works but without the return true and return false thingy that i desired to have, ANY BETTER WAY THAN THIS?

```
import os
path = '../'
folder = os.listdir(path);

def bla(pattern):
    for book in folder:
        if book[-3:] == 'txt':
            data = open(path+''+book).read()
            if pattern in sanitize(data):
                print(book + " contains " + pattern)
            else :
                print(book + " does not contain " + pattern)

bla('the')
```

Comment: so, what doesn't work for you?

Comment: Stuff that's wrong here: You're telling us the desired result but not the result you got. You reference, but don't provide, the `sanitize()` function. You say you want 'the', but the code is looking for 'jane'. You're overwriting `y[pattern]` or `n[pattern]` on every book, so you'll only get one result; you want to append to a list, not replace an entry in a dict.

Comment: basically i think what i want to accomplish is not to print within the function, if (bla('the') print something else: print something 
i want to accomplish this, any ideas 
(also ignore sanitize functions, a function just removes commas etc. like if the word is the, it removes `,`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
m1 = re.compile(r'.*?\.txt$')
pattern = 'yourpattern'
m2 = re.compile(r'%s' % (pattern))

for file in filter(m1.search, os.listdir(somedir)):
    if m2.search(open(file,'r').read()):
        print file, 'contains', pattern
    else:
        print file, 'does not contain', pattern
```

modify output per your tastes

Comment: no problem, put your desired output in for the heck of it and put the filter into the loop setup, no big change either way.  you can put the loop into a function, and then call it as part of an os.walk() if you need to traverse multiple dirs